# How to load external node module in node-webkit application

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, libusb, node-webkit

I have a problem with loading node-modules in my node-webkit application.

For example module `usb` (https://npmjs.org/package/usb).

It was successfully installed from npm (`npm install usb --save-dev`) and works in simple Node.js, also it was successfully rebuilded by `nw-gyp` for using in node-webkit.

I don't include `node_modules` folder in my `app.nw`, so after building using grunt, I have a following structure of files:

- app.exe
- nw.pak
- ffmpegsumo.dll
- icudt.dll
- libEGL.dll
- libGLESv2.dll
- [node_modules]

  - [usb]

    - binding.gyp
    - package.json
    - ...
    - [build]

      - [Release]

        - usb_bindings.node
        - usb_bindings.lib
        - usb_bindings.bdb
        - usb_bindings.exp
        - [obj]

          - ...

When I try to load this module in my appliacation, using following code:

```
var usb = require('usb');
```

I get an error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'usb'
```

Why node-webkit can't load this module?

p.s. All default modules like `path`, `url`, `http` works.

Comment: You probably need to package your modules with the node-webkit app in order to use them.

Comment: Yes, if I'll include my node_modules folder into app.nw, it works. But this decision increases size of .exe file. I use more than one module, and if I'll include all, I'll get near 50MB app.exe.

Comment: If size is a concern, you can probably remove somme of the .dll you are including. For instance, ffmpegsumo.dll and libEGL*.dll are not compulsory. You'll find references for this [here](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps). 
As for bundling your modules with your app, I fear there is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem has two reasons:

1. If I want to use node modules, which written on C++, I can't give for my app custom name (in my case 'app'), I should use default name 'nw'. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Using-Node-modules#3rd-party-modules-with-cc-addons
2. As I understood, it's not possible to load modules into appliacation from external folder 'node_modules' using function 'require'.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an absolute path to the source code of your module? (usually can be obtained from GitHub or a simple Google search)

for instance, if you want to load adm-zip module from an absolute path:

```
var AdmZip = require(pathToModuleSource + "/adm-zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

add permissiosn to your package.json

```json
    "permissions": [
        "usb",
    ],
```

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions#usb